# Android Date format. from string to Date

Tags: java, android, typeconverter

I have a string like this: 2015-01-31 16:00:00 +0000 UTC, I want to parse this string to date object.

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'

but failed.

Comment: You can write a simple parser, or use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SimpleDateFormat` for formatting the strings to date objects:

```
DateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss+z", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = originalFormat.parse("2015-01-31 16:00:00 +0000");
    String formattedDate = targetFormat.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```